# How to make a form action attribute to a specific file

Tags: forms

I'm making form in Drupal 7 website using php and trying to implement the under mentioned "action" attribute to the form. What i am trying to achieve is when the user clicks the submit button of the form the page should be redirected to **page--generator.tpl.php** in which the output of the form is shown.

This is what i am trying to achieve. This is the code from **node.tpl.php**, from where the user clicks the input and then print that input on the image on the next node i.e.**page--generator.tpl.php**

```
<?php
    if (!$is_front && $page ){
        echo"<form  method=POST action=".$base_url."page--generator.tpl.php>"
         ."<input id=post name=post_id type=hidden value=".$node_url."/>";
        if ($nid == 1){
        echo"<strong> Enter You Name <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
        }

    else {
        switch ($nid){
            case 2:
            echo
         "<strong> Enter You Quote <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
            break;
            case 4:
            echo
         "<strong> Hello Quote <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
                 ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
         break;
        }
        } 
         }
             ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You cannot use a template file as target of a form action. The proper way is using the form API: form builder, validation handler, and submission handler.

Comment: Please make an explicit question. What don't you know how to achieve, exactly?

Comment: If you're not familiar with Drupal's form API, d.o. has a [tutorial on using the form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/262422).

Comment: can anyone has a better solution ?