# Drupal Form Manipulation

Tags: forms

I'm making form in Drupal 7 website using php and trying to implement the under mentioned "action" attribute to the form. What i am trying to achieve is when the user clicks the submit button of the form the page should be redirected to **page--generator.tpl.php** in which the output of the form is shown.

This is what i am trying to achieve. This is the code from **node.tpl.php**, from where the user clicks the input and then print that input on the image on the next node i.e.**page--generator.tpl.php**

```
<?php
    if (!$is_front && $page ){
        echo"<form  method=POST action=".$base_url."page--generator.tpl.php>"
         ."<input id=post name=post_id type=hidden value=".$node_url."/>";
        if ($nid == 1){
        echo"<strong> Enter You Name <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
        }

    else {
        switch ($nid){
            case 2:
            echo
         "<strong> Enter You Quote <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
         ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
            break;
            case 4:
            echo
         "<strong> Hello Quote <strong>"
         ."<input type=text name=input>"
                 ."<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>";
         break;
        }
        } 
         }
             ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to go back and do some more reading about templates/themes/form api because that's going in the very wrong direction.

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: The question is the "Action" attribute of the form. i want to set the action to my desired file. how to set it? echo"<form  method=POST action=".$base_url."page--generator.tpl.php>"

Comment: Wordpress may be more suitable for you if you want to theme like this.

Comment: you are right, but drupal is the most powerful and flexible cms. and i love to work in drupal. i should do some more research on this. Thanks for the answers. if you can refer me some articles or blogs about templates/themes, i will be very thankfull. @Beebee

Comment: You can start with https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7 and http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-forms-drupal/

Comment: You already asked this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173615/how-to-make-a-form-action-attribute-to-a-specific-file) before, please don't double post here.